# Change the order of attribute options after creating a lot of configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes

Let's say you have 3 attributes. Size, Color and Texture.

The Size attributes has attribute options like this.

- M
- L
- XXL
- 40
- S
- XL
- 45

Meaning they are not in their correct order. Also meaning I cannot not on the frontend of the application sort these, since they "S" does not come before "M" in the alpabet.

I know Magento has it's sorting when you create attributes. But here has been created maybe 15-20 attributes, with around 200-600 attribute options.

And around 1000 products has been created using these attributes.

Is it possible, to change the sorting of the attribute values now, afterwards? Without breaking any connections between simple products and configurable products?

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the position of the attribute values in **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > yourattributecode**
And then use the **position** column like so:

[image: position changed in attribute values]

You'll probably have to reindex things after that.

Comment: Hello! 

This includes even when I have a few hundreds different options? I have done something similar before, and the connection between Simple Products and Configurable Products messed up? Did I do something wrong that time, or is that a possibility happening?

Comment: For this specific attribute I've got around 70 values, I don't think any number of value is the problem. Maybe your index was messed up the last time you tried. You can still try on a dozen of them and see it if works ;)